# How to reformat times in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, time

I have dates in YYYYMMDDHHmmss and I need to translate that to say 
Jun 6 - HH:mm

I can write a lookup table for the month conversion and code the whole thing myself. Is there a better way to go using standard javascript or node utilities?

Comment: https://momentjs.com/ Check this out. Not native, but great and widely-used utility.

Comment: Using moment `var a = moment("Jun 6 10:30", "YYYYMMDDHHmmss ")`

Comment: @PatrickRoberts MomentJS is the industry standard. It is highly highly highly highly highly recommended from anyone that has any experience with this. I've never seen anyone recommend anything other than momentjs

Comment: @Aravind that isn't correct usage

Comment: @Aravind still not correct ... try it

Comment: @charlietfl `moment('Jun 6 2017 10:30').format('YYYYMMDDHHmmss')` is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will look into on https://momentjs.com/ I used on nodejs

for exemple:

```
console.log(moment("201710022233322","YYYYMMDDHHmmss").format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm'));
```

Comment: I need to use MMM for the alpha version of the month. Other than that you were spot on.